# Trying profile routes on Backend with node js without using passport.js for authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication

I am trying to do profile page for user on my project without using passaport.js for authentication.
I created my middleware for auhtentiction which is check-auth.js. I am using insomnia for accessing my profile routes with token. I am getting error from check-auth.js.Is anyone can help me for this issue?
Thanks

1. This is middleware for authentication  (check-auth.js)

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const HttpError = require('../models/HttpError')

module.exports = (req, res , next) => {
  if(req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
      return next()
    }
  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]                       //We took token from headers authorization.( Bearer 'token')
    if(!token){                                                                 // We check token if it is falsy.If it is, We will send error for authentication failed
          throw new Error('Authentication failed')
    }

    const decodeToken = jwt.verify(token,process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY)            // for verifying token we need token and our secret key.
     console.log(decodeToken.userId)
     console.log(req.isLoggedIn)

     req.userData = {userId:decodedToken.userId}                                // We will use userid to delete and edit  recipes and meals. we need that.
     next()                                                                     // It is authenticated go next middleware

  }
  catch(err){                                                                   // if our token does not match with the token.
    const error = new HttpError('Authentication failed mi', 403)
    return next(error)                                                          // Send error
  }
}
```

2-This is my user controller for profile page.(users.js)

```
const profile = async(req, res, next) => {

  let existingUser
  try{
        existingUser = await User.findById(req.userData.userId,'-password').exec()
     }
  catch(err){
       const error = new HttpError('Profile failed, please try again', 500)
       return next(error)
     }
     if(!existingUser){
       const error = new HttpError('User does not exist',422)
     }


    res.status(200).json({user:existingUser.toObject({getters:true})})
}
```

3-This my routes for user    (user-routes)

```
const express = require('express')
const {check} = require('express-validator')
const router = express.Router()
const usersController = require('../controllers/users')
const checkAuth = require('../middleware/check-auth')

router.post('/signUp', [
  check('username').not().isEmpty(),
  check('age').not().isEmpty(),
  check('gender').not().isEmpty(),
  check('email').normalizeEmail().isEmail(),
  check('password').isLength({min:6})
],usersController.signUp)
router.post('/login',[
  check('email').normalizeEmail().isEmail(),
  check('password').isLength({min:6})
],usersController.login)
router.use(checkAuth)
router.get('/profile',usersController.profile)
module.exports = router
```

Comment: I found the solution. instead of  ``` req.userData = {userId:decodedToken.userId} ``` it needs to be ``` req.userData = decodedToken `` . It works